# Custom Markers for Mapbox with Mapkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mapbox, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm working on a Rails 7 application where I want to create a map of Stadiums. In my database, I have a "stadiums" table with attributes for longitude, latitude, and an image_data field containing logos for each stadium.

I'm currently using the mapbox via the mapkick gem to place pins on the map, with the locations of these stadiums. However, I'd like to replace the pins with an image/logo for each stadium on the map instead of the default markers.

Could someone please provide guidance or code examples on how to achieve this customization using the mapkick gem in Rails 7?

Here's my current code

**stadiums.index.hmtl**

```
<%= js_map stadiums_path(format: :json, place: params[:place], distance: params[:distance]),
             width: "1200px", height: "500px",
             controls: true,
             markers: 
               { 
                 color: "#000",
               },
             tooltips: { hover: false, html: true } %>
```

stadiums_controller.rb

```
 def index
    if params[:place].present?
      @pagy, @stadiums = pagy(Stadium.with_geolocation.near(params[:place], params[:distance] || 10, order: :distance))
    else
      @pagy, @stadiums = pagy(Stadium.with_geolocation.limit(100))
    end
  end
```

stadiums_helper

```
  def html_link_to(stadium)
    link_to stadium.name, stadium_path(stadium), target: '_blank', style: 'color: black'
  end
```

_stadium.json.jbuilder

```
json.extract! stadium, :latitude, :longitude, :image_data
json.label stadium.name
json.tooltip html_link_to(stadium)
```

Comment: Do you really need the gem? Mapbox has a very easy API so it's very likely going to be simpler to just do it from scratch then to figure out how to get a clunky gem to do what you want.

Comment: I did this many years ago and just used an ajax call to get JSON and then created markers with `L.marker(record.lat, record.lon], { title: record.name,  icon: someFunction(record), uri: record.path }).addTo(map);`

Comment: The advantage to that approach over just dumping data into a global via the view is that you can respond dynamically to the user panning and zooming the map and fetch the markers with geospatial queries.